# BIOS update/battery problem

Tags: dell, laptop, battery, bios

A while ago I spilled some coffee on my Dell XPS 13 9343 laptop, I opened it, cleaned it up, put in new keyboard and track-pad, etc.

Everything seemed to work fine again except that the battery wasn't charging and the volume cannot be adjusted . I recall when I first installed Ubuntu I also had the volume problem, which was solved by updating the BIOS. As I understand since I removed the motherboard I would have to update the BIOS again (read this somewhere), so I proceeded to update to the latest BIOS, in hopes that the battery issue may also be resolved by this.

I boot FreeDOS from a flash drive and execute the update file, however, I am met by the message saying that I would need a charged battery of at least 10% power to continue updating. I am unsure what to do next. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Did you have the power supply connected?

Comment: @CelticWarrior yes, it's the only way I can even power my laptop, as the battery is not charging.

Comment: It didn't give you an option to continue anyway? If not, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas regarding the BIOS update.